# Adjust the size of fields in forms

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am using SP 2010 and SPD designer 2010. How can I adjust the size of the fields in the new and edit forms?
For instance my NAME field is 50% larger than it needs to be.

Comment: try this one http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2008/01/25/modify-the-lengths-of-list-form-fields.aspx

Comment: Slight adjustment as this is an old post but it works, thanks

Comment: i added that as answer for benefits of community and me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SPD 2010 change the CssClass to ms-long and then insert this CSS styling to the code...

```
<style>
<style type="text/css">
.ms-long{width:100px;}
</style>
```

Comment: ...where do you insert the code, in the form file, e.g. "EditForm.aspx"?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the steps from below blog
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2008/01/25/modify-the-lengths-of-list-form-fields.aspx. this is old but will work.

this example for Annoucrment List.

1. Make sure you have at least one announcement in your Announcements
   list
2. Open your site in SharePoint Designer
3. Create a new page based on the Master page
4. Click on Task Panes > Data Source Library
5. Click on the Announcements list and click Show Data
6. Select the Title data value
7. Click Insert Selected Fields as > Single Item Form
8. Save the page and press F12 to Preview in Browser
9. Right click the page in the browser and click View Source
10. Select All > Copy
11. Create another new page in SPD and Paste all of the content into
     this new page's Code View
12. Click back into Design View
13. Select the Textbox control for the Title field

Now we just need to add a  block inside our first page that says something like below, then save the page.:

```
<style>
.ms-long{width:100px;}
</style>
```