# Change column width in SharePoint 2013 newform, editform, and dispform

Tags: 2013, jquery, css

I have found many people asking about changing the column width on a list view, but couldn't find much of anything on changing the column width on a form. Essentially, for longer questions, the "title" of the field pushes the page out to the point of having a horizontal scrollbar.

Is it possible to grab the specific elements in the form html table to limit the width of the left "title" column so that the words wrap and I don't end up with a scroll bar? I haven't been able to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can, via sharepoint designer.

It has been answered here:

[Adjust the size of fields in forms](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120161/adjust-the-size-of-fields-in-forms)